# Can't get windows to boot -

Tags: dual-boot

Summary

I moved partitions around to install Ubuntu 22.04 using UEFI. Now my Windows 10 partition does not work. I used boot repair and the results are here.

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/JM5w4QXGkQ/

Details

Ubuntu 20.04 told me I could now upgrade to 22.04. I said OK and it did a bunch of stuff, but I got errors so I decided to do a clean install.

The existing ubuntu was on an SSD partition. There were also partitions for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

As I started the process, I learned I needed to make a UEFI partition to install Ubuntu 22.04. I found I could not do that and keep the Windows and Ubuntu 16 intact. So I moved them to an HDD using the 'dd' command. I installed Ubuntu successfully (now I could let it do what it wanted to on the SSD). It complained about the partition table being in error. I adjusted the BIOS for this computer so that it would use EFI to boot but it had a compatibility mode that I also turned on. This machine is a Dell precision M6700. I ran the boot repair disk several times. This is the current GRUB menu.

*Ubuntu*

*Advanced options for Ubuntu*

*Windows 10 (on /dev/sdb1)*

*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (16.04) (on /dev/sdb5)*

*Advanced options for Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (on /dev/sdb5)*

**Currently, the machine boots Ubuntu 22.01 and 16.04. But it does not boot Windows. I get this error message.**

*error: can't find command 'parttool'*

*error: can't find command 'drivemap'*

*error: invalid EFI file path*

*Press any key to continue...*

The details of the boot repair are here.

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/JM5w4QXGkQ/

Thank you for your help.

Mark Weber

Comment: Boot-Repair tells you your Windows problem. "Grub-efi will not be selected by default because legacy Windows detected." You have UEFI system, but somehow installed Windows in old BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode. Microsoft has required UEFI with gpt partitioning since 2012. See also line 197, which means you did not restore NTFS to exact same sectors, so at minimum chkdsk required. Do not know what else may be required.

Comment: @oldfred thank you for the answers and suggestions. I was not able to reliably interpret the output of boot repair. I got the impression that I needed to reinstall windows. You confirmed it. I swallowed the pill and installed windows with UEFI. It was fairly painful. But I am now on the road to recovery.

Comment: @karel Thank you for the reference. I appreciate it.